# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Enable Direct Update only when WiFi connection is available?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I have a general query that the direct update of worklight can be enabled only when the device wifi connection is in active.

Few points in mind:

1. If user connected via cellular network worklight app can ask the user whether to continue the update process via cellular network.
2. Worklight server makes sure that client has the latest update though the user is connected via Cellular network. This cannot be compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Worklight framework does not provide any granular control over Direct Update. In other words - you cannot control (actually, not even the framework itself at this time) when it will be used and when it will not be used (WiFi or 3G).

If your application connects to the Worklight Server and an update is available, it will be presented to the end-user.

That said, work is always being done to enhance the Direct Update feature, so [you are encouraged to submit a feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25) about your needs.
Product designers frequently evaluate requests, so who knows... Also, if you are an IBM customer, do mention your needs via other official channels if required.